# Antonym of "crowded" that is not "uncrowded"

Tags: word-request

I want to describe two types of cities: one city is crowded, i.e., has a lot of population in a small area, while the other city is the opposite - it is *uncrowded*. For reasons of style, I want to use another antonym that does not contain the root "crowded". Any ideas?

Maybe the word "crowded" is unfit in this context. If so, what other words should I use?

Comment: Sparsely populated?  Deserted?  A ghost town?  Just how uncrowded is it?

Comment: And do tell us why *uncrowded* is unsuitable.

Comment: @Jim I feel the word crowded is suitable to describe smaller places such as streets and markets. When it comes to describe a town, city or country (larger areas), we probably prefer using the word 'dense'. Correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: @Maulik - The word _crowded_ works as a fine adjective for a city, although I'll grant you that "a crowded city" is probably often interpreted to mean "a city with crowded streets and marketplaces." As for _dense,_ I would never say, "a dense city," although I might say "a densely populated city."

Comment: @Jim uncrowded is suitable, but, for reasons of style, I prefer to use a word of a different root. It sounds a little better to not use two words with the same root too closely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To describe a city in this context, I would prefer this:

> New York City is very **densely populated.**
>   
>   Athens is **sparsely populated.**

Comment: "Very" is not normally used with *strong* adjectives or adverbs. You can say: "Very hot", but not usually "very boiling."

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Perhaps there's some truth to that, but "very densely populated" sounds quite natural to my ear. Moreover, that exact phrase is found in [many books](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22very+densely+populated%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=%22very+densely+populated%22&rls=en&safe=off&tbm=bks).

Comment: One upvote from me then!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Although I don't think your example perfectly matches this sentence, you touch on a good point. When writing English, you can often go through and replace "very something" with a more descriptive adjective to improve the quality of the writing. Some examples: *very hot* becomes *scorching*, *very cold* becomes *frigid*, *very tired* becomes exhausted, etc. It can make your writing much more interesting. Err.. I mean, it can make it enthralling. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not sure why you think dense is a "strong" word - there isn't a different word that means a little bit dense.

Comment: @Random832 to my way of thinking *densely* means compact, heavy, filled to capacity. To say something is very densely seems to me redundant, but if the written form is common, and it appears to be so, I'm very happy to acknowledge that I was mistaken.

Comment: The intensifier *very* can only modify words that are gradable, and since *boiling* isn't, **very boiling* doesn't work (except in an informal sense, the same way someone might say a woman is *very pregnant*).  Phrases like *very densely* and *very sparsely* are fine.  (Personally, I like *very*.  I think it's got a worse reputation than it deserves!)

Answer (score 5):

It has a high population **--->** a low population

A busy city **---->** a quiet city

A crowded street **--->** an empty street

The city centre is crowded **--->** the city centre is uncrowded

The city centre is chaotic **--->** the city centre is calm

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the following words or phrases:

> Canary Wharf on Christmas Day was ***completely deserted***.
>
> I went out of my hotel at 3am and the ***streets were empty***.
>
> The town I grew up in is ***very sleepy*** compared with the hustle and bustle of central Manhattan.
>
> After the zombies came, Moscow felt ***vacant*** and ***deserted*** - a mere shadow of the once proud city I had grown to love.

Comment: These phrases sound too strong. The uncrowded city I refer to is not "deserted", "empty", "sleepy" or "vacant". It has a healthy amount of population, like a village or a suburban region, but it not crowded like a big city.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: "sleepy" does not mean "deserted". It just means that it is not noisy and crowded.

Comment: @Matt. The OP probably wants a single word to describe it better. As Erel Said, the phrases you described sound too strong.

Comment: You can also say "felt deserted" which does not mean there is nobody there - merely that there is very few people there. I.e. it is uncrowded.

Comment: Does the word "sleepy" say anything about the density of population? It sounds like describing more the character of the people and not their density...

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: A "sleepy village" is a village that is peaceful and quiet. It does not mean that the people there are sleepy, or that they are docile. Indeed, as anyone that has lived in a sleepy village will tell you, often the residents can be anything but sleepy and docile!

Comment: I would say that *sleepy* is the opposite of *busy* or *bustling*

Comment: I would agree with @Jim that an apt opposite of _sleepy_ is _bustling,_ but I also agree with Matt that _sleepy_ has a strong connotation of being _uncrowded_. I suppose _Denise awoke in the sleepy, crowded city_ is possible, but that does have a rather oxymoronic feel to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you were talking about an apartment instead of a city, I would suggest *roomy* or *spatial* as antonyms for *crowded*. However, I don't think either one of those words works very well when describing a more sparsely populated city.

What I think you could use, though, (at least in some contexts) is the term ***breathing room***:

> Tokyo is a crowded city. Nagano has a lot more breathing room.

[**TFD**](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=breathing%20room) lists “sufficient room for easy breathing or movement” as a definition of *breathing room*, with this example usage: *“moved to the country to find breathing room.”* A related expression is *elbow room*.

In a more formal context, a related term is ***population density*** (the population of a city divided by its area). Crowded cities have a high population density, while "uncrowded" cities have a relatively low population density.